# How to properly disable a button in IE10?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer-10

Guys I have tested this code in Chrome, Firefox, IE 7 8 and 9. Only in IE10 it doesn't work.

```
 $("#upload_file").live('click', function() {
     $('#upload_file').prop('disabled', 'disabled');

     //then do some more codes like ajax
 }
```

When I click the upload button, it should disable that button to avoid double clicks. This works properly on other browsers except in IE10. in IE10 it doesn't look disabled, but it wont execute the other codes below it. So I'm assuming it really disabled the functionality, not the button

Comment: live() is deprecated and removed in newer versions of jQuery

Comment: what should that be then?

Comment: `.on()` with event delegation.

Answer (score 1):

Disabled should be set to a boolean value:

```
$('#upload_file').prop('disabled', true);
```

As per the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/prop/):

> The .prop() method should be used to set disabled and checked instead
>   of the .attr() method.

```
$( "input" ).prop( "disabled", false );
```

Comment: Yes, the button literally disabled the other codes. It wont execute any more codes after the disabled part. What I want is just to disable the button functionality, not the other codes

Comment: the "//do some other codes like ajax" part. See above. That button when clicked will upload a file, when I put that disabled code, it wont upload a file anymore, meaning, it really disabled the whole code block

Comment: That's expected behaviour. Disabled means just that, it is no longer possible to upload a file or click on the input. You might want to use `e.preventDefault()` or the `blur()` method if you want to only disable the file input box.

Answer (score 0):

It seams to me that your problem came from using old version of jQuery. Because IE 10 recently created while your jQuery i guess is 1.6 which is not optimized for new version of browsers. I strongly suggest to you update to new version, unless you are re-factoring existing code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this with `.on()` with event delegation:

```
 $(document).on('click', '#upload_file', function() {
     $(this).prop('disabled', true);
     //then do some more codes like ajax
 });
```

you can use closest static parent to the target element("_#upload_file_") that may be a `<div>, <table>` which holds the button.

To re-enable the button:

```
 $(document).on('click', '#upload_file', function() {
     $(this).prop('disabled', true);
     $.ajax({
         url: your url,
         type: your type,
         .......
         success:function(){

         },
         complete:function(){
            $('#upload_file:disabled').prop('disabled', false); //<----here
         },
         error: function(){}
     });
 });
```

Comment: still doesn't work. It disabled the whole code block of upload_file button. I cant upload a file anymore

Comment: @BelmarkJuneCaday you have to enable it somewhere in the function, as you mentioned `//then do some ajax` so in the `success or complete` function you can re-enable them by assigning `true to false` in the .prop method.

Comment: So its like disabling it then re-enabling it again immediately? What's the sense? Because After disabling the button, I have to do ajax call.

Comment: I think you have misunderstood it, 1.disable on click 2. do your ajax call and when your ajax gets completed only then you can enable in the `complete: function(){}` of your ajax you are doing. Hope you get it.